# Form Processing: empty TD tags generated with foreach loop

Tags: php, html, form-processing

I'm trying to process a pretty simple rental quote form, basically the form gets filled out and then the data gets sent to an email.

My issue is how the item section is being formatted. Right now I'm trying a table and populating it with a foreach loop. The main problem is it's generating empty td tags for some reason.

Here's the output, I've added some borders so you can see the empty cells being generated:

[image]

And here's the section of my php code where I'm processing this (if you'd like to see the entire code, just let me know):

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
$name = strip_tags($_POST['renter_name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['renter_email']);
$message = strip_tags($_POST['renter_message']);
$subject = "Quote Request";
$rentalItems = ($_POST['item']);

// $items  = implode(',', $_POST['item']);

$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Sent by:</strong> ".$name."</p>";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Items:</strong></p>";

$msg .="<table name='rental_items' style='border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid black;';> 
                <thead style='text-align:left;'>
                    <tr>
                        <th sytle='padding-right: 5px;'>Item Name and ID</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>    
                </thead>
                <tbody>";
                    foreach($rentalItems as $item) { 
                        $msg .="<tr>
                            <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>". $item['name'] ."</td>
                            <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$item['quantity']."</td>
                        </tr>";
                     } 
       $msg .= "</tbody>
</table>";   

$msg .= "<p><strong>Message:</strong> ".$message."</p>";
$msg .= "</body></html>";
```

Currently I'm running a row and two cells in the loop. But for some reason it's treating each td as its own row.

Ultimately I would like that Quantity number along side the Name and ID info.

I'll be honest with you, I haven't worked with tables in years so it could possibly be something super simple I'm missing or have wrong. Or it could be how I'm structuring this whole thing in general.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated. Again, if you need any more info, just let me know.

Here's the item section of the form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item[][name]" value="Name: <?php the_title();?> <?php echo "<br>"?> ID: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'id_number', true); ?>" id="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
<label for="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="form-image" /></label>
<input type="text" name="item[][quantity]"/>
```

Comment: Does your `$item['name']`  contain any HTML?

Comment: This simplified (replacing your foreach with a for) version works: https://3v4l.org/ZNEPe

Comment: @BrettGregson It does contain a <br> tag, I've added that form section to my post. See above.

Comment: Try `var_dump($item['name'])`. Everything looks correct but I suspect something in there is breaking the markup

Comment: forgive me, form processing is not my strong suit. Where should I place `var_dump($item['name'])` ?
Oh I see what it's supposed to do. Okay, let me try and implement it and I'll post the results.

Comment: Try replace your foreach with  `foreach($rentalItems as $item) { var_dump($item['name']); }`

Comment: Here's what I got from that:
`string(31) "Name: Awesome Chair
ID: 50" NULL NULL string(39) "Name: Gold Throne Loveseat
ID: 126" NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `item[][name]` and `item[][quantity]` for the data, you will end up with alternate array elements containing the different values...

```
Array(0 => ("name" =>"somename"), 
         1 => ("quantity" =>1))
```

When you foreach over this array, it will display one value or the other, but not the 2 together.

So it would be easier (I think) to use a for loop and take it in steps of 2...

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($rentalItems); $i+=2) { 
    $msg .="<tr>
               <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>". $rentalItems[$i]['name'] ."</td>
               <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$rentalItems[$i+1]['quantity']."</td>
            </tr>";
}
```

Alternatively - rename the arrays to be `item[name][]` and `item[quantity][]` so that the data is separate, but you can then use `$item['name'][0]` and `$item['quantity'][0]`.

Comment: Hey Nigel, I just ran your for loop and neither the tr's nor td's rendered.

Comment: Sorry - I had made a mistake in the `for()` part - should be `count($rentalItems)` I think.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much Nigel! I see what you mean now about the array items stacking rather than being in a sense grouped. I'll definitely have to study your code for the future. Thanks again!